# Why did I get a "No Method" error?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently going through "Agile web development with Rails - 4th edition" and I am stuck.
The checkout button is supposed to bring up an orders page, but instead I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Orders#new

Showing C:/Sites/depot/app/views/orders/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @order.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %>
```

After spending a lot of time trying to figure this out, I copied all the source code from the books website, which still didn't work. I even checked the errata and book forums and found nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code from the views/orders/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %>
      prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.text_field :name, size: 40 %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.text_area :address, rows: 3, cols: 40 %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
 <!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.email_field :email, size: 40 %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pay_type %><br />
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES,
                  prompt: 'Select a payment method' %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->
    <%= f.submit 'Place Order' %>
<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the Orders Controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @orders = Order.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @orders }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @order }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  # GET /orders/new.json
  def new
    @cart = current_cart
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    @order = Order.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @order }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 
          'Thank you for your order.' }
        format.json { render json: @order, status: :created,
          location: @order }
      else
        @cart = current_cart
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /orders/1
  # PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

This is the Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card", "Purchase order" ]

  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  # ...

  validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
  validates :pay_type, inclusion: PAYMENT_TYPES
end
```

Comment: If `form` is a partial included in the `new` view, are you passing in a local that perhaps can be accessed as `order`, vs `@order`?

Comment: You don't have an @order.

Comment: @DaveNewton Could you elaborate please? Sorry, I am very new to programming

Comment: @order is nil and `form_for` is blowing up attempting to determine what `Model` it represents.  I can help you debug the issue.

Comment: @order is not nil for `/orders/new`. Check his function, it is there. It is nil for `/orders/index`, as it is @orders and not @order. This shouldn't affect the form on the other page though.

Comment: @adback03 If he his hitting the url he says he is hitting, then, yes, it is `nil`.  I understand that it is set in the controller action, but something else is causing this instance variable to be `nil` in this case.  It does appear to be routing to a different action than `Orders#new`.  We just need to figure that part out.

Comment: Are you using rails 3 or 4?  Type `rails -v` in the terminal.

Comment: I am using Rails 3.2.13.

Comment: I was wondering because the Rails 4 edition book includes Rails 4 code, so I just want to make sure that the entire rails project you are pulling down is compatible with Rails 3.2.x

Comment: Try to find:  `Started GET ... Processing by ...` in the terminal output or the `log/development.log`.  This will tell us what URL rails believes you are accessing and which controller/action is handling it.

Answer (score 0):

The `form` view believes that `@order` is `nil` here:

```
1: <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
```

What is the path that you are hitting in the browser? `/orders/new`

It does appear that `Order#new` is setting `@order` to `Order.new`, so I am wondering if you are actually hitting that controller.

Rails will route requests to controller actions based on what is setup in `routes.rb`.  Run `rake routes` to see the routes you can access in the url.

Rails has conventions such that if you access the `/orders/new` using a simple GET request, it will route your request to the `new` action of the `OrdersController` and will attempt to render the associated `app/views/orders/new.html.erb` - unless you customize some aspect of this.

I would add a `puts "Order is set to: #{@order}"` in the `new` action following the `@order = Order.new` assignment to ensure it's actually going through that path.

Comment: Ran a rake route test and orders/new was one of the available routes if that's what you are asking? I also added the code you told me to, and nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, so when you hit `localhost:3000/orders/new` what does it show in the terminal?  There should be an indication of which controller is handling the request.

Comment: Well now after restarting the server, nothing happens when I click the "Add to cart Button" ... so I can't even hit a checkout button because it only routes when the cart isn't empty.